# VSCODE export or copy a debug watch expression to another program

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to export or copy an array of data from the VSCODE debug watch window to another programs like Excel or Matlab in order evaluate the data? [As you can see on the picture there is no option for copying the array. It is also not possible to multiple select the elements of the array and then copy it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56mdy.png)

I am using VSCODE Version 1.26.0 on MacOS and the Cortex-Debug extension tool. Does anyone have a solution for it?